# MySQL 5.7 not running windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows-10-desktop

MySQL version - 5.7.11

I am unable to run mysql server on my windows 10 even after running command prompt as an administrator and marking run as administrator in the exe files for mysql and mysqld.

Following are the contents of log file present in the data directory -

```
2016-02-28T18:44:37.478791Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-02-28T18:44:37.479292Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2016-02-28T18:44:37.480293Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.11) starting as process 504 ...
2016-02-28T18:44:37.643005Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-02-28T18:44:37.644506Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-02-28T18:44:37.645507Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2016-02-28T18:44:37.646508Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-02-28T18:44:37.651010Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-02-28T18:44:37.655562Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-02-28T18:44:37.716605Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-02-28T18:44:37.736603Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-02-28T18:44:37.757664Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2016-02-28T18:44:37.760134Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibdata1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2016-02-28T18:44:37.956704Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibdata1' size is now 12 MB.
2016-02-28T18:44:38.047061Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
2016-02-28T18:44:38.500757Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
2016-02-28T18:44:39.211654Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file .\ib_logfile101 to .\ib_logfile0
2016-02-28T18:44:39.226714Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2016-02-28T18:44:39.226714Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2016-02-28T18:44:39.226714Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2016-02-28T18:44:39.423633Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2016-02-28T18:44:39.477796Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2016-02-28T18:44:39.657048Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2016-02-28T18:44:39.703088Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-02-28T18:44:39.704591Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-02-28T18:44:39.731614Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2016-02-28T18:44:39.975606Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2016-02-28T18:44:39.977607Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2016-02-28T18:44:40.036710Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2016-02-28T18:44:40.036710Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2016-02-28T18:44:40.132743Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: sys_virtual table created
2016-02-28T18:44:40.134252Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-02-28T18:44:40.185456Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-02-28T18:44:40.236970Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-02-28T18:44:40.292644Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.11 started; log sequence number 0
2016-02-28T18:44:40.421142Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2016-02-28T18:44:40.642217Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-02-28T18:44:41.016703Z 0 [Note] Salting uuid generator variables, current_pid: 504, server_start_time: 1456685077, bytes_sent: 0, 
2016-02-28T18:44:41.056673Z 0 [Note] Generated uuid: '539246ef-de4b-11e5-a535-b8ac6f65e9fe', server_start_time: 1456685581, bytes_sent: 3022329767296
2016-02-28T18:44:41.106807Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 539246ef-de4b-11e5-a535-b8ac6f65e9fe.
2016-02-28T18:44:41.496798Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-02-28T18:44:41.644892Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2016-02-28T18:44:41.697459Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-02-28T18:44:41.698960Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-02-28T18:44:41.698960Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-02-28T18:44:41.699962Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-02-28T18:44:41.703464Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2016-02-28T18:44:45.751401Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2016-02-28T18:44:45.787570Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-02-28T18:44:45.788067Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-02-28T18:44:45.828191Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2016-02-28T18:44:45.828675Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-02-28T18:44:45.829175Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-02-28T18:44:45.829676Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-02-28T18:44:45.830175Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.031497Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.031969Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.598005Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.598485Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.598988Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.599486Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.600036Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.600486Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.600986Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.601486Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.601988Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.602487Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.602487Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.602988Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.603489Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.603989Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.604490Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.604990Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.605490Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.605490Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.605990Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.606491Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.606991Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.607492Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.607992Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.608493Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.608493Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.608993Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.609535Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.610023Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.610511Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.610511Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.611026Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2016-02-28T18:44:46.611524Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-02-28T18:44:46.611996Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-02-28T18:44:46.721456Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to D:\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2016-02-28T18:44:46.729458Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 160229  0:14:46
2016-02-28T18:44:48.212545Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1209970
2016-02-28T18:44:48.213546Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2016-02-28T18:44:48.214047Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-02-28T18:44:48.214047Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-02-28T18:44:48.214547Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-02-28T18:44:48.214547Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-02-28T18:44:48.215047Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'keyring_file'
2016-02-28T18:44:48.259518Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-02-28T18:44:48.260518Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the required tables does not exist as seen in the log file you presented: "Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist." If you have not already  "run mysql_upgrade to create it," then [Perhaps manually initialize the data directory](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had tried the solution that you have mentioned and this didn't help because for running the command mysql_upgrade you need to have mysqld running which was the issue.

Also, now I am able to do my work after uninstalling this version and using the MySQL v5.5 instead and the installation of v5.5 had the option to setup the MySQL server which was not there when I installed v5.7 which could have been the issue.

But still if I am giving all the rights required to run mysqld, mysql and command prompt why I am not able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You should run "mysqld --initialize" before server start.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html